# Bridging two WiFi networks without a dongle

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+

I would like to connect my Raspberry Pi 3B+ to a WiFi network and use it as an access point for its own network. I need it to act as a proxy so that I can connect multiple devices and they appear as a single device on my network. Ideally I want to use it to connect IoT devices and regulate them through iptables.

Is it possible to connect my Pi to one WiFi network and act as an access point for another without using a WiFi dongle? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The WiFi on the Pi can only do one function at a time, so either be an access point or be a WiFi client.

Note that if you want to use the Pi for IoT devices this way, IPTables with NAT is probably a better solution than a proxy.